# How can I save the text of a richtextbox with all the color into a json to put it back after

Tags: c#, json, wpf, richtextbox

I'm on WPF and I have a richtextbox with a lot of different color, size, bold/underline text ect and I wanted to know now how can I save all this text to a json file or to a parameter of an object to put it back later

```
RichTextBox.SaveFile(); // dont exist
```

I cant serialize the Richtextbox.Document it give me a loop error
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-extract-the-text-content-from-a-richtextbox) and the [documentation of TextRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textrange.save), I created a small method to get the content of the RichTextBox in RTF format:

```
string GetRtf(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        textRange.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        stream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can also save the content directly to a `FileStream` instead  of a `MemoryStream`.
You can use this method to get the content as a string and save it wherever you want. Later you'll need `Load()` to read it back into your control.