# C# WPF Can't get data binding for RichTextBox to work both ways

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, richtextbox

I'm trying to bind formatted text from a RichTextBox to a field in a View Model, with the intentions to eventually save that text along with other fields to a JSON.

I followed this solution: [Richtextbox wpf binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding) to get data binding on the RichTextBox. This was successful in initial tests, as I was able to set to set the RichTextBox's text programmatically by assigning a value to the string it's bound to.

The issue is when I want to have data the user types into the RichTextBox saved and bound to the string in the View Model. This is what it's binding to to in the View Model:

```
        private string description;
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return description;
            }
            set
            {
                description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Description));
            }
        }
```

And this is how the RichTextBox is set up in the xaml:

```
<RichTextBox local:RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"  x:Name="rtb" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" AcceptsTab="True" Margin="10,5,10,0" FontSize="16" MinHeight="270" MaxHeight="270" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></RichTextBox>
```

I also have the RichTextBoxHelper set up as described in the answer linked above.

I have tried to find a way to change the data type of the string, but can't figure out exactly what the data type would be, or if that even truly is the issue.

I've also found some guidance on how to save the RichTextBox's text, like with this answer: [How can I save the text of a richtextbox with all the color into a json to put it back after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68726344/how-can-i-save-the-text-of-a-richtextbox-with-all-the-color-into-a-json-to-put-i) but this seems to preclude data binding and instead would require me to first set the text in the xaml.cs and then somehow get the result to the View Model, which I don't like the idea of. I'd much prefer to stick with data binding.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The behavior you use is only tracking changes for currently created TextRange (which is created as the result of the string to FlowDocument conversion). You should modify the code of the RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml property changed callback to listen to the RichTextBox.TextChanged instead of the TextRange.Change event. This is necessary because when typing into the RichTextBox the control will not modify the existing TextRange but add new TextRanges. A FlowDocument (or RichTextBox content) is composed of multiple TextRanges. In addition your behavior converts to/from XAML and not text.

Comment: Because the property is named `RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml` the behavior works correct by anticipating the input string to be a valid XAML. Also the result is the current XAML representation of the document. I's not clear if this is what you expect. It appears like you assume you will get the plain text of the document. If this is the case then you would also have to change the conversion format and rename the property to `RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentText`.

Comment: Also your behavior does not manage the MemoryStream properly. Unless you want to create leaks you should dispose the MemoryStream in a using statement or using expression. As a note, MemoryStream implements IDisposableAsync.

Comment: And using a StreamReader instead of Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes to read from the MEmoryStream allows for async stream handling, which should be a significant improvement for large documents (otherwise your application will freeze). Same applies to writing to the MemoryStream.

Comment: Not sure why you use XAML data format at all. If you are interested in RTF format then you could use DataFormats.Rtf instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I'm still trying to learn how FlowDocuments work and this was a great help in that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add DataContext from your Xaml file to view model class?
At first add xmlns with your namespace and then add data context with view model class.

```
<Window x:Class="TestProgram.BuildAssistantWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModelTest="clr-namespace:TestProgram.ViewModels">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModelTest:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, I did, and the data context should be changing when I change views. It's able to bind to other fields when I navigate from view to view just fine. Thanks for the reply, though!